# Airflow with Google Autentication

Tags: google-authentication, airflow

Currently, I am trying to integrate the airflow with google authentication.

I am able to open the login page, but every time I try to login, I always get this error:
"You don't seem to have access. Please contact your administrator."

I have created user in airflow, the username is same with my email that will be authenticated.

Do I miss something? Any other configuration needed?

For configuration settings, I followed everything stated in this link: https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#google-authentication

Thanks,
Maria

Comment: Just double checking did you change the domain setting in the config to match the email you are trying to login with. i.e. domain = example.com

Comment: Hi Chris, 

Yes, I changed it. 
Before I was using the wrong domain.

Thanks, 
Maria

Answer (score 13):

I solved this issue by removing quotes from the value of `domain` in `airflow.cfg`

So I changed my config from:

```
[google]
client_id = google_client_id
client_secret = google_client_secret
oauth_callback_route = /oauth2callback
domain = "example1.com,example2.com"
```

to:

```
[google]
client_id = google_client_id
client_secret = google_client_secret
oauth_callback_route = /oauth2callback
domain = example1.com,example2.com
```

The documentation is misleading

Comment: This is crazy, I just ran into that issue and that was it. I'll take a look at their bug tracker and report this

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was I set the domain to alias domain, not using the original domain.

After I changed to the original domain, it works.

Comment: For localhost, how did you specify it?

Comment: domain refers to the user's email domain - if you are using gmail.com as your google email, then it will be gmail.com as domain in localhost